# django 1.10 url dispatcher not working

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-1.10

I'm trying to simply give an app url an option of `/headless/` to make it show a different template.

My `project/urls.py` has:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^datastore/', include('datastore.urls')),
]
```

My `app/urls.py` has:

```
app_name = 'datastore'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^datastore/(?P<headless>"headless"{1})/$', views.index,name='index'),
]
```

I'm getting a 404 error with the above.

I've also tried:

```
url(r'^datastore/(?P<headless>"headless"?)/$',
url(r'^datastore/(?P<headless>\w{1})/$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^datastore/(?P<headless>\w+)/$', views.index, name='index'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the prefix `/datastore/` from the app `urlpattern`:

```
app_name = 'datastore'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<headless>"headless"{1})/$', views.index,name='index'),
]
```

According to [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/):

> Whenever Django encounters `include()`, it chops off whatever part of
>   the URL matched up to that point and sends the remaining string to the
>   included URLconf for further processing.

So, the url pattern in your project's settings consumes the `datastore/` prefix.  You should be able to check that this is so by trying `/datastore/datastore/headless/` (this should work with your current configuration).

Notice, however, that the combination of regular expression matches either `/datastore/headless/` or `/datastore//` (the same in all your variations).  This may not be what you want.  Wilfried's answer (which does not address the real issue here) shows you how to better do what I think you intend to.

Comment: *doh* ... got it `url(r'^(?P<headless>headless{1})/$', views.index, name='index'),`

Answer (score 0):

It's may be your regex on your url.

If you need access to url :

- /datastore/
- /datastore/headless/

you can create two url, pointing to the same view.

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
   url(r'^datastore/$', views.index, name='index'),
   url(r'^datastore/(?P<headless>(headless))/$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

If you want, it's not necessary to use a parameter. If you have only headless like possibility.

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
   url(r'^datastore/$', views.index, name='index'),
   url(r'^datastore/headless/$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Comment: This is useful for getting rid of the double `/` required by the original regular expression.  However, it does not provide the `index` entry point with any information about whether `headless` was present, or not.